# Erroneous font rendering in urxvt

Tags: fonts

I have

```
urxvt.font: xft:Deja Vu Sans Mono:size=10
emacs.font: DejaVu Sans Mono-10
```

in my `.Xresources`.  Does this mean different versions of the
font are used?  In the urxvt (or xft?) version there are several
errors in 'polytonic' Greek letters.  E.g., GREEK SMALL LETTER
UPSILON WITH PERISPOMENI shows up as GREEK SMALL LETTER UPSILON
WITH MACRON.  Can something be done about this?

In fact, the same error occurs with the default font.

PS.
I have now found the error is due to something called
anti-aliasing, a method of smoothing fonts.  It can be eliminated
by adding `:antialias=false` to the font selection, but this
yields a jagged rendering.
It would be nice if there were a better solution.

Comment: The characters that you are asking about may not be in the given font.  Both urxvt and emacs use (different) lists of fallback fonts to provide glyphs which are missing from the preferred font.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, `describe-char` confirms that the correct character is in
`xft:-PfEd-DejaVu Sans Mono-normal-normal-normal-*-13-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1`